# Proving theorem in Isar with no local assumptions

Tags: isabelle

The statement `n+0 = n` is quite trivial to prove:

```
theorem add_0: "n+0 = (n::nat)"
  apply(simp)
  done
```

Upon trying to convert it to *Isar* however, I've noticed that it doesn't seem to require any assumption. So in the this attempt:

```
theorem add_0: "n+0 = (n::nat)"
proof -
  thus "True" by simp
qed
```

It fails, as there are "*`No current facts available`*". This second attempt also fails:

```
theorem add_0: "n+0 = (n::nat)"
proof -
  from add_0 show "True" by simp
qed
```

This time with the error "*`Failed to refine any pending goal`*".

Is it possible to prove a statement that requires no `assume` clause in *Isar*? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with `thus "True"`

1. As you've noted, the proof state that you begin doesn't have any assumptions, therefore no facts in the proof state. The abbreviation `thus` expands to `then show`, as we have no facts in our proof state it doesn't make sense to use `then` so we should instead replace it with `show`.
2. `show "True"` is saying that we want to prove `"True"` instead we want to prove the goal of the theorem. We can use the schematic variable `?thesis` to refer to the original thesis of the theorem. The error `Failed to refine any pending goal` is just saying that if we were to prove that `True` is true, it wouldn't help solve the goal of our thesis.

So we can prove our original theorem with an Isar proof using the following pattern.

```
theorem add_0: "n+0 = (n::nat)"
proof -
  show ?thesis by simp
qed
```